# Setting Timezone with Solarium PHP

Tags: php, solr, solarium

So this Timezone option looks very useful.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Working+with+Dates#WorkingwithDates-TZ

Example,

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/select?q=*:*&facet.range=my_date_field&facet=true&facet.range.start=NOW/MONTH&facet.range.end=NOW/MONTH%2B1MONTH&facet.range.gap=%2B1DAY&TZ=America/Los_Angeles
```

Note **TZ=America/Los_Angeles**

But I can't work out how to set this option via the Solarium API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t tried this, but it *should* work with `addParam()`, which comes in handy whenever Solarium does not offer a dedicated API for a Solr feature.

In your case, this *should* be the solution:

```
$query->addParam('TZ', 'America/Los_Angeles');
```